# Istio destination rule subsets not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio

MY istio destintion rules are not working, getting below error in kiali

[image]
VirtualService and destination rule for echo service:

My calling `echo-svc:8080` and `echo-svc:8080/v1` from my another virtualservices , I'm not able to do route in specific version.

When making request from another virtualservice: `echo-svc:8080/v1` or `echo-svc:8080`, I'm getting response from both the subsets.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: echo-vsvc
spec:
  hosts:
  - "echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local"
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/v1"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: echo-destination
spec:
  host: echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v0.1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v0.2
```

If I'm attaching my echo-service to gateway and then making service to `v1` endpoint via istio-ingress, my all requests are routed to required k8s service, but if it's internal(echo service not attached to gateway) envoy is not routing the requests to required k8s service..

Update:

```
 $ > k get pods --show-labels
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     LABELS
echo-deploy-v1-bdf758994-8f54b    2/2     Running   0          2m56s   app=echo-app,pod-template-hash=bdf758994,version=v0.1
echo-deploy-v2-68bb64684d-9gg2r   2/2     Running   0          2m51s   app=echo-app,pod-template-hash=68bb64684d,version=v0.2
frontend-v2-569c89dbd8-wfnc4      2/2     Running   2          12h     app=frontend,pod-template-hash=569c89dbd8,version=v2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my mistake, for istio destination rules to work be very careful about these: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/.

My mistake was of **named port** for service. Updating it from "web" to "http-web" worked for me.  It should be of form : `<protocol>[-<suffix>]`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-svc
  labels:
    app: echo-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http-web
  selector:
    app: echo-app
---
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error the instances of your service are not labeled with  `version: v0.1` or `version: v0.2` and that's why the destination rule cannot find instances for the subset.

Verify that they are labeled by executing:

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels
```

And for quick testing you can label them:

```
kubectl label pod [pod_name] version=v0.1
```

Comment: thanks for help, but I've pods with those labels. Still I'm missing something or making some mistake.