# Istio Virtual Service is not working very well

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, istio, seldon

I find that the Rewrite feature of my Virtual Service is not working very well. Here is my Virtual Service and DestinationRule yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: leads-http
  namespace: seldon
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-system/seldon-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /seldon/seldon/leads/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: leads-leads
        port:
          number: 8000
        subset: leads
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: leads-leads
  namespace: seldon
spec:
  host: leads-leads
  subsets:
  - labels:
      version: leads
    name: leads
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        idleTimeout: 60s
```

When I send an http request：

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/seldon/seldon/leads/v2/models/leads-lgb/versions/v0.1.0/infer'
```

I find that the istio-proxy service prints 404 not found in the logs:

```
"POST /seldon/seldon/leads/v2/models/leads-lgb/versions/v0.1.0/infer HTTP/1.1" 404
```

even though I expect:

```
POST /v2/models/leads-lgb/versions/v0.1.0/infer HTTP/1.1
```

I am not sure what's happening. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: pretty strange. your rewrite rule is seems correct. Ill take a closer look next few days. interesting story

Comment: in the meanwhile.. can you help me a bit? 1. your istio version; 2.There is working example with 2 nginx pods in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450007/9929015. Any possibility to  deploy those manifests and check if it work for you at all or not? cause again, your rule looks good for me

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is incorrectly configured `DestinationRule` or service name connection.

[DestinationRule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/):

These rules specify configuration for load balancing, connection pool size from the sidecar, and outlier detection settings to detect and evict unhealthy hosts from the load balancing pool.

Version specific policies can be specified by defining a named subset and overriding the settings specified at the service level.

**Note**: policies specified for subsets will not take effect until a route rule explicitly sends traffic to this subset.

[DestinationRule-Subset](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#Subset):

[image]

It seems to me that  `name` should go first in the structure. At least I haven't seen/met another examples.

So in your case correct(at least I hope) DR is:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: leads-leads
  namespace: seldon
spec:
  host: leads-leads
  subsets:
  - name: leads
    labels:
      version: leads
```

However, if that wont help - I encourage you to check [this self-resolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197734/istio-destination-rule-subsets-not-working/54209833#54209833):

Dont you have the same situation with named service port? I mean as per [Explicit protocol selection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/#explicit-protocol-selection) you should add suffix in service name...
`name: <protocol>[-<suffix>]`